# Android architecture components liveData and room - what is minimum requirements?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I realize its in alpha stage, however I'd like to know if the android architecture components like liveData and room have any minimum requirements ? such as min android api/sdk etc.  I looked [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)
but its not showing me if there is any requirement.  Can i assume i can use this right back to at least android ICS ?

Comment: Room, at least, requires a `minSdkVersion` of 14 or higher.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind showing your source ?

Comment: Step #1: Create an Android project. Step #2: Add the dependency. Step #3: Set the `minSdkVersion` of the project to `1`. Step #4: Read the error message to find out the `minSdkVersion` of the dependency.

Comment: But commonsware is there is any other way to find the minSDKVersion of the project before adding dependencey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can assume that it goes back to ICS at least. Also starting support library version 26, minSdk becomes 14. So I assume new architecture libraries will be the same.

According to googlesamples, lowest API version is 14, which is Ice Cream Sandwich.

Here are the links to the gradle files for the minSdk 14 apps:

[Github Browser Sample gradle file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle)

[Persistent Content Provider Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample/app/build.gradle)

Comment: good idea to check the sample.  commonsware idea was excellent as well.